# How to dynamically change the content of a page on loading

Tags: jquery, list, ready

My problem is to execute a function when a new page is loaded. I have two pages (index.html and location_page.html). In the first one there is a list of labels. When the user click on one element of this list, he is redirected to the second page that should dynamically load the info associated. I tried to use function `ready` but it doen't work. Here is my jQuery code

```
$("#location_title").ready(function(e){
    console.log("executing the function");
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div class="location_info">
    <div class="location_text">
    <div id="location_title"></div>
        <div id="location_description"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="location_img"><img src="./img/strutture01.jpg" class="location_image"/></div>           
     </div>
```

The first page also has a method like this (i call a 'ready' function) and it works, but it doesn't works on the second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a query string saying `location_page.html?info=1`

Use this function to get the query string value,

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

So on document ready, call the function

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    value = getParameterByName("info");
    if (value == '1')
    {
        $("#location_title").show();
        // Do your stuff
    }
    console.log("executing the function");  
});
```

**`getParameterByName()`** function is taken from **[Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/500725)**

### UPDATE:

Replace this

```
$("#location_title").ready(function(e){
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: I already thought of something like that, but my problem is that it doesn't even print "executing the function"

Comment: @user1482243: Replace this `$("#location_title").ready(function(e){` with `$(document).ready(function(){`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using HTML `onLoad` attribute in HTML `<body>` tag and from that call your function in the Javascript..

i.e. i Javascript;

```
function doSomeThing(){ /*your code*/ }
```

and in HTML;

```
<body onload='doSomething()'>
   <!-- your html body -->
</body>
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

For that you'll want a simple self-executing anonymous:

```
(function() {
    $("#location_title").ready(function(e){
        console.log("executing the function");
    });
})();
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.. If i refresh the page (the second one) it visualize it, but when i click on the link it does not work.ìs